# App Crashes After Facebook Login

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, xcode4.2, iphone-4

i made an iphone App which I've submitted in the App store . The App is there in the App Store for about an year . It has basically a faceBook Login button . One fine day it crashes, the moment i click my Facebook login  Button in my iPhone 4, iPhone 4s.When i try to run it in my Macbookpro it also crashed . I'm  getting the error
 "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull lowercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2125ce8**'".........

It works fine in my iPhone 3Gs...please help me .How can a iPhone App crash After working fine  for about an year. Is it something related to Facebook updated methods or related to iPhone version.The App crashes exactly after FBrequest is called !please help me I'm losing my reputation .......

Comment: Did you enabled NSZombie, if not Enable it and get the debug logs ? It hints you are calling method on NULL object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a string in your app that is set to point to NSNull. The app crashes when you are attempting to make that string lowercase.
Since NSNull points to a static object of type NSNull, trying to send the message "lowercaseString" to it causes the app to crash. (if it had been nil, Objective-C would simply ignore the message)

Could it be that there is a string somewhere that used to be set to a value, but for some reason now has been removed and is set to NSNull? It could be due to changes in the FaceBook-API but it could also be caused by changes in what the server is sending to you, different information in your facebook account and many other things. The parser you are using may be setting NSNull instead of nil whenever a NULL-value is sent by the server.

Bare in mind that it might also not be related to Facebook at all, since you find different behaviour on iPhone3GS.

You could try to look around for NSString values in your code that you are trying to make lowercase. Use the debugger to try to identify strings that are of type NSNull. You can compare your strings to NSNull like this:

```
if (text == (id)[NSNull null]) {
    // String is NSNull!
}
```